# Orange object on back of jet-engine pylons, what is it?

Tags: aircraft-design, lockheed-tristar, engine-pylon

Watching this [Video of a L-1011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W0KcQLImuo), I noticed an orange/brown object on the back of the jet-engine pylons I never saw before.

- What is it?
- What's the purpose of it?

[image: L-1011 Jet Engine pylons]

Comment: It looks like a simple infrared jammer as in this [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_countermeasure#mediaviewer/File:ALQ-144_IRCM.jpg), but seems strange on an airline

Comment: @ManuH maybe a former military craft that never had the thing refitted

Comment: Great catch! I don't know if I'd have ever noticed it.

Comment: Probably "rachet freak" is right, the 747 seen later in the video doesn't have one fitted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Manu H is right. It is an IR jammer device. [Saudi (corrected from the comment of David Richerby:)**Royal Flight** airliners tend to have them (root of the wing, next to the light)...](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Saudi-Arabian-Royal/Boeing-747SP-68/1308171/L/)

Comment: That is one of the nicest SP photos that I've ever seen! I just sat there staring at it for a few minutes... the angle and zoom really emphasize the muscular attributes of the 747 fuselage. Magnificent!

Comment: The photo you link to is a 747SP that's part of the Saudi Royal Flight so might be expected to have more defensive equipment attached than your average airliner. For example, this [Saudia 747](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Saudia---Saudi/Boeing-747-4H6/2493020/L/&sid=a38099e2152f12034c4374699d5086ad) doesn't seem to have jammers at the wing root; likewise, this [Saudia freighter](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Saudia---Saudi/Boeing-747-4H6/2493020/L/&sid=a38099e2152f12034c4374699d5086ad).

Comment: @David Richerby, you're right I also recognized that, so the Mistery remains.

Comment: Now I see, the Royals used a L-1011 before they bought the 747SP. I always thought that what I saw in the video was a commercial aircraft.
http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/1739630/

Comment: @DavidRicherby you linked twice the same photo

Comment: @Federico Oops. Too late to fix it now. The second one was supposed to be a head-on view of a 747 freighter that also didn't have the jamming device at the wing root but it's not worth the time it would take to find the right link again.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is an infrared counter-measure device, i.e. a device intended to protect aircraft from "heat seeking" missiles. Saudi no doubt flies to some potentially dangerous spots in the Middle East.  [See this article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_countermeasure)